# applicationGuildCommands function deploys globally

Tags: discord.js

I am following the discord.js guide on here https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#registering-slash-commands and I tried executing the code on there regarding the applicationGuildCommands function which is supposed to deploy changes on my commands locally (guild scope) but instead it does globally. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong since I did exactly what was posted on the guide.

This is my index.js file:

```js
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Intents, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');


const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// Fetch commands
const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

client.commands = new Collection();

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}


// Fetch events
const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, commands));
    }
    else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, commands));
    }
}


// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

And this is my deploy-guild.js file

```js
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));


for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```